# How to configure hadoop with eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop, mapreduce

I am new in hadoop I have downloaded the hortonworks sanbox image and mounted that with virtualBox. And sanbox ui is coming in the localhost when I am typing 192.168.56.101/ in the Chrome. Also I am able to log in to hadoop shell with hue/hadoop username password. Now I want to run a simple program in eclipse. I have added `hadoop-0.18.3-eclipse-plugin` to the eclipse and then tried the following steps.

```
1.choosed map/reduce from eclipse.
2.went to hadoop location editer 

localhost name:localhost
under map/reduce master
port:9000
under DFS master
port:9001
```

But I am getting this error

> Cannot connect to the Map/Reduce location: localhost Call to
>   localhost/127.0.0.1:9001 failed on connection exception:
>   java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information

Virtual box is running.

Comment: is it `192.168.56.101` or `localhost`? Those two contradict each other.

Comment: @RemusRusanu is the url i am running hortonworks sandbox locally but  i saw a tutorial to configure hadoop with eclipse see this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TavehEdfNDk

Comment: For anyone following this thread: If you're on the Hortonworks 2.4 sandbox, the port you're looking for is 8020, not 9000.

Answer (score 2):

1. Add required hadoop dependancy jar files to your eclipse class path.
2. In your main method of your mapreduce program add these lines

   ```
   Configuration conf = new Configuration();
   conf.set("fs.default.name", "hdfs://localhost:50000");
   conf.set("mapreduce.job.tracker", "localhost:50001");
   ```
3. if you are running in virtual machine change the localhost to
   required ip address (where hadoop demon runs).you can get the ip
   address bytyping `ifconfig`
4. run the mapreduce program as simple java program
       .you will get the output in the eclipse console.